# How to add a container to the force-layout?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, containers, force-layout

Based on this simple basic example of a force-layout:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642

I try to add an container with scrollbars calles `svg2` with the following  code i added to the force-layout:

```
var content = document.getElementById('viz');

var svg2 = d3.select("#viz")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 3000)
.attr("height", 300);
```

and also this div element:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="viz" class="content"></div>            
</div>
```

I just wonder, what i am doing wrong here, because the container does not appear at all. But the same code works on a empty code without the force-layout. Thanks so much for the help! Here is the full code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    .link {
      stroke: #ccc;
    }

    .node text {
      pointer-events: none;
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    </style>

<div class="container">
  <div id="viz" class="content"></div>            
</div>



    <body>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>



var content = document.getElementById('viz');

var svg2 = d3.select("#viz")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 3000)
.attr("height", 300);




    var width = 960,
        height = 500

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .gravity(0.05)
        .distance(100)
        .charge(-100)
        .size([width, height]);

    d3.json("graph.json", function(error, json) {
      if (error) throw error;

      force
          .nodes(json.nodes)
          .links(json.links)
          .start();

      var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
          .data(json.links)
        .enter().append("line")
          .attr("class", "link");

      var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
          .data(json.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .call(force.drag);

      node.append("image")
          .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
          .attr("x", -8)
          .attr("y", -8)
          .attr("width", 16)
          .attr("height", 16);

      node.append("text")
          .attr("dx", 12)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name });

      force.on("tick", function() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
      });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Is that div outside the body?

Comment: No, it is inside. I just edited it.

Comment: Your HTML is still incorrect. Please edit it again.

Comment: Div should be outside of the body?

Comment: First, you are not closing the body. Second, the div is inside a script.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, I just edited again. But I think that closing the body is not really needed, because it's still working without the closing. Or i am wrong with that?

Comment: Now it is outside the body again! If you don't share the exact structure of your HTML it will be impossible to help you.

Comment: Ok, i leave it now how it is and won't change it again to not confuse you :)

Comment: Just solved the problem by myself. Thanks for the help-

Comment: post your solution please

Comment: Yeah, the solution is, that I use  `<div class="scroll"> </div>` instead of `<div class="container">
  <div id="viz" class="content"></div>            
</div>` and it works very fine. But unfortunally I cannot say why the `container`is not working.